# Assign site name based on matching strings (without separating the address)

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I am trying to assigna SiteName based on some matching criteria. I have completed the task using the below steps, hwoever was wondering if I could achieve the same result without the  "separate" and "pivot_longer" functions

**Code:**

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Author,                       ~"Author Address",
     "BA",        "METRO NORTH; DALLAS",
     "OA",       "RBWH; TPCH; TOPEND",
     "OB", "CABOOLTURE HOSPITAL; CALIFORNIA UNI",
    "AOS",           "CABOOLTURE HOSPITAL; RBWH",
       "KB",                     "WOMENS HOSPITAL"
  )


df


df %>% 
  separate (`Author Address`, into = c("Site1", "Site2", "Site3"), sep = ";", remove = F ) %>%
  rename (Address = `Author Address` ) %>% 
  pivot_longer (cols = - c(Author, Address), names_to = "Site", values_to = "Author Address" ) %>% 
  mutate (`Author Address`  = str_to_upper(`Author Address`),
          Site = case_when (grepl ("METRO NORTH", `Author Address` ) ~ "Metro North Health",
                            grepl ("CABOOLTURE HOSPITAL", `Author Address` ) ~ "Caboolture Hospital",
                            grepl ("TPCH", `Author Address` ) ~ "Prince charles hospital",
                            grepl ("RBWH", `Author Address` ) ~ "RBWH")) %>% 
  #filter (!is.na (Site)) %>% 
  select (Author, Address, Site ) %>% 
  distinct () %>% 
  group_by (Author, Address) %>% 
  summarise (Site = paste0(Site, collapse = ", "  )) %>% 
  ungroup () %>% 
  mutate (Site = str_trim (str_remove_all (Site, pattern = ", NA$"  ), "right"  ) )
```

**Output:**

[image]

I have compelete the task but wish to do without the "separate" and "pivot_longer" functions and possibly a short code

Comment: You will likely need the `separate` and `pivot_longer` parts of the code, because they are, errrr, necessary. You can have _other_ functions (from other packages, even from base R) that will, essentially, do the same. Why do you want to eliminate them?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am trying to eliminate the `separate` function because I must supply a separator. Unfortunately, the data comes in very dirty (a lot more complex than my sample data), and I can't predict the semicolon will always fall in the right spot, which makes separating very tricky. I thought matching the strings without separating the field will be the best way to go.